# Shortening Hex bytes in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net-2010

So I also have this code in my project to mass replace bytes of files:

```
    Dim byteError As Byte() = { _
        }
```

1. I'm going to add 260k bytes in that part of code. However those 260k are in the format "0008080898F698EEFDF5F5F5B9F698EEFFBFB etc..."
2. but VB needs it as "&H0, &H0, &H8, &H etc.." which makes it 700k+ characters and VB would crash.

My question is, is there a way to add the bytes as a string then convert it (as is) or at least a way to not use &H in each byte?
Basically, I want to keep my Hex bytes as short as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you save your data in a file and set it as an embedded resource instead of having it as source code?

Comment: Assuming that I saved the bytes as a .txt file, do you have an idea how to use it in the same place as a byte? Basically, converting it from a String back to Byte so it would fit in that code.

Comment: No, but these are probably good kewords to Google: visual basic bytes embedded resource

Comment: Just gave it a quick search but in vain. Couldn't find anything useful about it.